# How to use ISC KEA DHCP to inform "DNS" and "GATEWAY" to my DHCPv4 clients?

Tags: networking, network-interface, dhcp, isc-dhcpd

To illustrate I will inform the configuration of my ISC KEA DHCP (DHCPv4) and my DHCP client. Below is the configuration I am currently using for my ISC KEA DHCP (DHCPv4):

```
$ cat /usr/local/etc/kea/kea-dhcp4.conf

{
    "Dhcp4": {
        "interfaces-config": {
            "interfaces": ["enp0s17"]
        },
        "control-socket": {
            "socket-type": "unix",
            "socket-name": "/tmp/kea-dhcp4-ctrl.sock"
        },
        "lease-database": {
            "type": "memfile",
            "lfc-interval": 1800
        },
        "expired-leases-processing": {
            "reclaim-timer-wait-time": 10,
            "flush-reclaimed-timer-wait-time": 25,
            "hold-reclaimed-time": 3600,
            "max-reclaim-leases": 100,
            "max-reclaim-time": 250,
            "unwarned-reclaim-cycles": 5
        },
        "valid-lifetime": 4000,
        "renew-timer": 1000,
        "rebind-timer": 2000,
        "subnet4": [{
            "interface": "enp0s17",
            "subnet": "192.168.56.0/24",
            "pools": [{
                "pool": "192.168.56.3 - 192.168.56.254"
            }],
            "option-data": [{
                "name": "domain-name-servers",
                "data": "192.168.56.1"
            }, {
                "name": "routers",
                "data": "192.168.56.1"
            }]
        }]
    },
    "Logging": {
        "loggers": [{
            "name": "kea-dhcp4",
            "output_options": [{
                "output": "/usr/local/var/log/kea-dhcp4.log"
            }],
            "severity": "INFO",
            "debuglevel": 0
        }]
    }
}
```

This is the configuration I have in my client for its network interface...

```
$ cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s17

BOOTPROTO=dhcp
DEVICE=enp0s17
IPV6INIT=NO
USERCTL=NO
ZONE=public
```

With this configuration - without using ISC KEA DHCP (DHCPv4) - my client works perfectly.

```
$ cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s17

BOOTPROTO=static
DEVICE=enp0s17
DNS1=192.168.56.1
GATEWAY=192.168.56.1
IPADDR=192.168.56.100
IPV6INIT=NO
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
NM_CONTROLLED=yes
ONBOOT=yes
TYPE=Ethernet
USERCTL=NO
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Difficult to answer the question with only this data. Have you done any debug or have any errors in logs?

Comment: The settings shown here are correct. In my real case this settings was failing because of a basic conceptual error. I was sending more than one "DNS" and "GATEWAY" because the file "kea-dhcp4.conf" had several "subnet"s. Just to be clear what each thing is in the file "kea-dhcp4.conf": "DNS" -> "domain-name-servers"; "GATEWAY" -> "routers".